# Spring MVC @RequestBody variable Integer protection for a string

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

How can I protect variable **Integer number** in wrapper (container) **WrapperClass** to recieve a string instead of a number?

Code:

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "MyOwnURL", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseSomething createTeam(HttpServletRequest r, @RequestBody WrapperClass wrapperClass) {
    //method body                                      
}

class WrapperClass{
  Integer number;
  //getter and setter
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to "protect".

What do you expect when request contains "abc" for the `number` property?

For me the best idea is to define string only properties and add getters/setters which convert the properties on fly. The logic how to process invalid values could be placed in the getters/setters (if you want to return some default values for invalid content) or you can add controller validation e.g. hibernate validator based. Then you can annotate the properties with custom annotation and validators to check correct values.

```
class WrapperClass{
  @MyMustBeNumberAnnotation("must.be.number.error")
  String number;
  //getter and setter
}
```

Comment: When I use @ModelAttribute annotation soo I can use BidindingResult that can catch this problem. But I don't know how to send an array of numbers with one Integer and one String as **NO** JSON data.

Comment: send array of strings always

Comment: Thanks. This solution works for me. But I'm not sure if is this the best solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an alternative. Would be great if the alternative exists